# Change CSS value in an external CSS file that I don't control?

Tags: css, google-chrome, tinymce, userscripts

I use a CMS which utilizes *TinyMCE* editor as a visual editor. Its CSS is weirdly edited so that ul-lists won't show bullets and paragraphs don't have any space between one another.

Is there a simple and convenient way to change the appearance that is defined in a specific CSS file **on a server I don't have access to?** I need to override these attributes in `www.site.com/global.css`:

```
ul { list-style-type: square; }
p { margin: 10 px; }
```

I believe there is an easy way to do it with Greasemonkey but I'm no good with scripting. Oh, and I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Add your stylesheet after `global.css` and apply styles you want in your css.

Comment: I don't have access to files on the server. Otherwise I might as well just edit the global.css. I need a way to override the css

Comment: Have you tried [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish/)?

Comment: I have but to no avail. Here's what I did

body#tinymce, .mceContentBody ul {list-style-type:square !important;
}

Comment: for some reason, Stylish doesn't affect TinyMCE css at all

Comment: Stylish will work.  You need to specify it for the correct iframe.  Link to the target page or save the source HTML and http://pastebin.com/ that.

Answer (score 3):

Because you use TinyMCE you will need to have your CSS file loaded into the TinyMCE iframes head and not into your main page.

Use the [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css) setting for this. It's a way to overwrite TinyMCE default CSS.

**Update**: Without access to the server files nor TinyMCE configuration you still have access to the TinyMCE API. Have a look at this options to [load the CSS](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.loadCSS) to where you need it. You should place your CSS file someplace on the internet/intranet where you can access it.

```
// Loads a CSS file dynamically into the current document
tinymce.DOM.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads a CSS file into the currently active editor instance
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads a CSS file into an editor instance by id
tinyMCE.get('someid').dom.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');

// Loads multiple CSS files into the current document
tinymce.DOM.loadCSS('somepath/some.css,somepath/someother.css');
```

**Update2**: It is possible to load a CSS string into the iframe head. For this use something like the following *userscript*:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @match   http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==

var css_to_add = 'p { margin: 10 px; }'; // example
var iframe_id = 'your_editor_id' + '_ifr'; // place your editor id here+'_ifr'
with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow) {
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (!h.length) return;
    var newStyleSheet = document.createElement("style");
    newStyleSheet.type = "text/css";
    h[0].appendChild (newStyleSheet);
    try {
        if ( typeof newStyleSheet.styleSheet !== "undefined" ) {
            newStyleSheet.styleSheet.cssText = css_to_add;
        }
        else {
            newStyleSheet.appendChild( document.createTextNode ( css_to_add ) );
            newStyleSheet.innerHTML = css_to_add;
        }
    }
    catch(e){}
}
```

Save the code as `MyCSSFix.user.js` and install it in Chrome per [**these instructions**](https://superuser.com/q/450893/41023) (after editing the indicated spots for your details).

Comment: Correct. Also, I forgot to mention that TinyMCE is in iFrame with src as javascript

Comment: Still no good, client side, unless OP has a server (or wants to write a full-fledged extension).  Is there a function that will accept a full CSS string, instead of a file? (couldn't find one in a very quick search). Then *that* would be user-scriptable.

Comment: Okay update 2 looks good.  Put a userscript wrapper around it, and I'd say it's the answer. +1

Comment: @BrockAdams: what do you mean by userscript wrapper? - do you mean script tags?

Comment: @Thariama, I edited your answer to show you. The OP could theoretically install that script in Chrome and be good to go. In practice, it needs details the OP has not provided and probably needs AJAX/timing compensation.

Comment: http://userstyles.org/styles/20377/wordpress-compose-increase-font-size this script works fine in Firefox but I can't make it work in Chrome either via TamperMonkey or as an Chrome extension. I mean, what it does isn't really what i need to be done but it only takes a little tags altering.

Comment: You would use that style with Stylish, not Tampermonkey or as an extension. However, Chrome does not handle all iframes properly.  Hence the need for more involved techniques. This answer's "Update 2" approach should work, but you need to tune it for your exact target page/site.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes added to the tag inline should override previously loaded stylesheet declarations.

```
<p style="margin:0px;"></p>
```

should override any p-margin styling in global.css

Comment: well, the output of TinyMCE-edited text looks just fine, it's just that I want to be able to edit text convenietly in the editor window. I mean, the visual part of the editor itself is incorrect because of the css that it uses.

Comment: Oh okay, I get your problem then...
If you're the only one who uses the editor, I'd say some browser fix script - i.e. greasemonkey - might actually do the trick, but sadly I know very little about that.

Comment: Yeah,that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out – how to setup Greasemonkey or any other kind of browser fix so that it would do the trick.

Comment: Greasemonkey could do it, but that's **Firefox**.  For Chrome, use a straight userscript or use Tampermonkey.  However (1), Stylish is the easiest smartest way to accomplish this (usually), in either browser.  However (2), the OP has not specified enough detail for us to provide any more guidance.  We need to know the **exact** HTML and CSS in question.

Comment: http://www.dj-store.ru/css/global.css here's a css file I need to have altered. Specifically, second line

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

should be 

* { margin: 10; padding: 0; }

and ul { list-style: none; } should be ul { list-style: disc; }

Comment: @maximrrrr, that's a start, but we need the HTML, that contains the iframe, so that we know how to hook-in the style overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

on your css file use **!important**

```
ul { list-style-type: square !important; }
```

Comment: I don't have access to the file or any other file on the server, I need some kind of browser trick.

Comment: access to the CMS, that's all

Comment: and you don't have access to the TInyMCE theme?